# How to batch insert into TimescaleDB from .csv files?

Tags: timescaledb

In the TimescaleDB docs, it mentions being able to [import data from a .csv into an empty hypertable](https://docs.timescale.com/v1.2/getting-started/migrating-data#import-data) using their GO program. My question is how would I go about import data from .csv files to a non-empty hypertable? My .csv files are all the same structure, but they all may not all be available when the first table is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the PostgreSQL COPY command, or better yet:  https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy